# Sencha Touch 2: Give a different itemTpl to nested list leaf nodes

Tags: sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

In my nested list I have 2 levels. Currently it shows a standard list. When you click an item it takes you to a list of that item's children. Those children are the leaf nodes. So when you tap one of those it takes you to the detail card for that item. I'd like to use a different list item template for the children than the parent items. Is there a way to use Ext.XTemplate to check if an item is a leaf node or not?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: 
Simply update the **x-list-item-leaf** class

```
.x-list-item-leaf{
    color:red !important;
}
```